# Clear Contents on Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I use to delete contents of specific cells if certain words appear. Currently I have this set up in 1 sheet on my workbook.

However I would like it to work over multiple sheets.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CC()
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("O9,O11,O13,O15,O17,O19,O21,O23,O25,O27,O29,O31,O33,O35,O37,O39,O41,O43,O45,O47,O49,L10,L12,L14,L16,L18,L20,L22,L24,L26,L28,L30,L32,L34,L36,L38,L40,L42,L44,L46,L48,L50")
    If InStr(1, rCell.Value, "A") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "B") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "OK") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "C") Then
        rCell.ClearContents
    End If
Next rCell

Set rCell = Nothing
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CC"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following:

```
 Dim rCell As Range
 dim sheet as worksheet
 For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each rCell In sheet.Range("O9,O11,O13,O15,O17,O19,O21,O23,O25,O27,O29,O31,O33,O35,O37,O39,O41,O43,O45,O47,O49,L10,L12,L14,L16,L18,L20,L22,L24,L26,L28,L30,L32,L34,L36,L38,L40,L42,L44,L46,L48,L50")
      If InStr(1, rCell.Value, "A") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "B") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "OK") Or InStr(1, rCell.Value, "C") Then
         rCell.ClearContents
      End If
      Next rCell
 Next

 Set rCell = Nothing
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CC"
```

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for taking the time to reply! I am a massive amateur at this! Where exactly should I put this extra code?

Comment: Thanks Doug. This code works but still only for Sheet1. I know its very vague but could there be something else I am missing?

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks guys!!

Comment: @paulm99 Please feel free to give a guy a check mark and/or an uptick for helping out :D. Also sorry I missed the Sheet1 to sheet thing O_o

Comment: No problem! How do I do that?

Comment: besides the relevant answer there is an up and a down button, and there is a place for you to mark as a checked (which means the answer you accepted).